# Is it possible to import decimal quantity while products imports for some of the products magento 2?

Tags: magento2, quantity, import-products

I am thinking to allow decimals quantity to some of the products while products import Magento 2.

If anyone have idea please guide me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can do it. in your product import CSV file, you can set `is_qty_decimal` to **1** and set your qty as the decimal.

[image]

While from the backend you can do it from `Advanced Inventory`

[image]